# List an entity from an Object via LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following Classes object.I want to list only PIds.

`Classes.Select(x=>x.Entities)` only returns me a list of `Entities` object. I need to query further to list only **PId**'s.

```
Classes: [
{
  Id: "ea7c8653-0aa1xxxxxxx",
  Name: "Math",
  Entities: [
              {
               PId: "0552619b-5303-4ac5-a1d9-xxxxxx",
               Name: "Upper",
              },
              {
                PId: "0885214-5303-4ac5-a1d9-xxxxxx",
                Name: "Lower",
              },
              {
                PId: "6522145-5303-4ac5-a1d9-xxxxxx",
                Name: "Medium",
              }
          ]
     }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show some code

Comment: I have tried `Classes.Select(x=>x.Entities)`, and I am stuck further query

Comment: Try this `Classes.SelectMany(x=>x.Entities.Select(y=>y.PId))`

Comment: I mean for the specific problem you have. An attempt to get the nested ids

Comment: @GiladGreen: I am fully on board with having to try something before posting here; but we're close to faulting OP for not using something that he clearly doesn't know exists. Based on `Classes.Select(x=>x.Entities)`, Intellisense will not be of any help to OP to figuring out what he needs to do, which means that he can't know whether he's doing it wrong from the get go, or he's missing a piece of the puzzle. Technically, anyone can solve anything by reading a sufficient amount of information, but direct help (such as SO) is often more efficient _and_ effective for finding the missing piece.

Comment: @AleksAndreev: Answers should be posted as an answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

### **The problem**.

I understand from your example that `Classes` is a list of class objects. Let's assume a simple class definition, for the sake of example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}
```

---

Try and answer the following question: what is the type of `names` in the following snippet? Try to answer it, don't just read on.

```
var names = Classes.Select(x=>x.Name);
```

> `names` is a `List<String>`, because `MyClass.Name` is of type `String`.

---

What is the type of `entities` in the following snippet? Try to answer it, don't just read on.

```
var entities = Classes.Select(x=>x.Entities);
```

> `entities` is a `List<List<Entity>>`, because `MyClass.Entities` is of type `List<Entity>`. 
> This is important to understand: `entities` is not a *list of `entity` objects*, but rather **a list of lists of `entity` objects**. This makes a meaningful difference.

---

It is possible to turn a `List<List<Entity>>` into a `List<Entity>`.

[**SelectMany**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) is used for exactly that reason. Essentially, it performs a normal `Select`, and then automatically merges the lists into one big list (usually called "flattening" the list).

```
var entities2 = Classes.SelectMany(x=>x.Entities);
```

`entities2` is a `List<Entity>`, because `SelectMany()` has flattened the `List<List<Entity>>` for you.

However, I'm not sure if this is what you want or not. It depends.

---

---

### **The solution**.

It depends on what you want.

**If you want a flat list of all `pId` values:**

```
var pidList = Classes.SelectMany(c => c.Entities).Select(e => e.PId);
```

In this case, `pidList` will be a `List<string>`.

---

**If you want a separate list of `pId` values for every `class` object**, i.e. without flattening the list:

```
var pidListPerClass = Classes.Select(c => c.Entities.Select(e => e.PId))
```

In this case, `pidList` will be a `List<List<string>>`.

---

> **Footnote**
>   In case someone wishes to point it out, I'm not really focusing on whether the variable types are `IEnumerable<T>`, `List<T>` or any other collection type. The only meaningful distinction I'm trying to make is between a single object or a collection of objects. `List` is simply the easiest to understand and the shortest to type.